# Adding scrollView to another scrollView not working

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a view which I set in interface builder, I added a scrollView in IB and now I'm trying to add another scrollView which will be only part of the parent scrollView.
onside the child scroll view I'm trying to use a dynamic sized label which will reside under anothe fixed label.

```
UIScrollView *ingredientsScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]
                                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 287, 280, 300)];
ingredientsScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
UILabel *ingredientsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 310, 70, 21)];
ingredientsLabel.text = @"מצרכים";

UILabel *baseLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 325, 70, 21)];
baseLabel.text = @"חומרים לבסיס";

UILabel *baseIngredientsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [baseIngredientsString sizeWithFont:baseIngredientsLabel.font
                                  constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                      lineBreakMode:baseIngredientsLabel.lineBreakMode];

//adjust the label the new height.
CGRect newFrame = baseIngredientsLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
baseIngredientsLabel.frame = newFrame;

//i added text to the string in some way
baseIngredientsLabel.text = baseIngredientsString;

[ingredientsScrollView addSubview:ingredientsLabel];
[ingredientsScrollView addSubview:baseIngredientsLabel];

[scrollView addSubview:ingredientsScrollView];
```

When I run the app the child scrollView is not added nor the labels?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that all variables aren't nil?

Comment: Yes, everything seems OK.

Comment: What's the frame for scrollView? Is scrollView being added to the view?

Comment: It's added using IB, the frame is the whole screen minus the status bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child scrollview is getting added ok, it's just that you don't notice it as it has a white background and the parent scrollview also has a white background. Also you have not set your contentSize property for either of the scrollViews so they don't scroll. Your labels are offset out of the current view and you can't scroll to see them.

Try a bit of this kind of thing to analyse your views:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400,9999);
ingredientsScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400,9999);
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
ingredientsScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: The problem was solved when I set the contenSize of ingredientsScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try first.

Try adding your `ingredientsScrollView` directly to the view. If it doesn't show up, you probably have a problem with the method not being called. That will also test to see if your labels are being added to the `ingrediantsScrollView`.

Also, in regards to your dynamically sized UILabel. Why are you not just using `[baseIngredientsLabel sizeToFit]`? It's a lot simpler than what you are currently trying to do with the frame.